# Jquery Mobile - Adding a responsive Leaflet map to page content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, leaflet

I need to make a Leaflet map fit inside a JQM page that also includes a header. The problem is that the page is scrollable and I can't see the bottom of the map without scrolling. I need the whole page to fit the window size, without any scrolling.

Here is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/51Lv7ppt/

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="mapPage" data-theme="a"> 
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
            <a id="backButton" href="#" data-rel="back" 
                data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>
            <h1>Map</h1>
        </div> 

        <div id="map-content" data-role="content">
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
        <a id="curLoc" data-role="button" data-icon="location" data-iconpos="notext"></a>

    </div> 
</body>
```

css:

```
#mapPage, #map {
  height: 100%;
}

#map-content{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px; 
  margin:0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
#curLoc{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the map's containing elements all to 100%, it takes 100% height of the body, that means including the header which is 42px. But the `mapPage` element is padded 42px on top because of the header, so it has 42px extra at the bottom. You can correct that using CSS calc. Change:

```
#mapPage, #map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Into:

```
#mapPage {
  height: calc(100% - 42px);
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Now `#mapPage` doesn't overflow the 42px on the bottom and `#map-content` and `#map` take 100% of `#mapPage` which is 100% - 42px; Now it fits like a glove.

Fork of your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lcu21pdn/

If using `calc` is not an option for you, you can correct the height of element `mapPage` by using plain javascript or since you're using jQuery already, jQuery before initializing the map:

```
var element = $('#mapPage');

element.height(element.height() - 42);

var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
```

Another fork of your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pjv22wgk/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wasn't aware you could do that with css.

Comment: Since CSS3 it's part of the spec, only Opera mini doesn't support it. See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: I see it's not supported in some Android browsers, that may be a problem.

Comment: I've added another solution if using `calc` is not an option for you

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured, works ok now.
By the way, if you use page events, don't put the resize in 'pageinit', it won't work. I added it in 'pageshow' and it works fine.

Comment: I'm absolutely not familiar with jquery-mobile :) But i'm guessing the `mapPage`element isn't added to the DOM at `pageinit` so a query for it will fail.